# One model or 178 models?

Tags: regression, logistic, chi-squared-test, modeling, finance

I am doing a school project, where I am modeling next quarter's stock price using the information about the stock in the current quarter. The main goal is to see if we can find any statistically significant parameters for the predictive model as that would reject the efficient market hypothesis. The data has 178 stocks with 7 parameters (e.g. trading volume, sector, EBITDA). The timespan is 72 quarters (= 72 observations). For modeling the stocks we are using logistic regression with information on whether the price goes up or down. My teammates and I have made two different attempts of modeling the problem:

1. A single model of all the companies using the logistic regression. Based on the p-value related to the parameters we find that EPS and EBITDA are statistically significant.
2. One logistic regression model for every company making a total of 178 models. The p-value for each model for a specific parameter is captured. Based on a confidence interval of alpha = 0.05 only 5% of the models should reject the parameter. To test that we set up a Chi-squared test for each of the parameters we would look something like this:

Expected values for accepting H0: 169.1, for rejecting H0: 8.9

Actual   values for accepting H0: 165, for rejecting H0: 13

Based on the Chi-squared test we would either accept or reject the null hypothesis that the parameter doesn't have any influence on the market. This would also be done for the other parameters. In this way we can find which parameters are statistically significant.

To my surprise my professor seems to like both approaches. However, what is interesting is that the two approaches gives completely different results. The first approach finds that EPS and EBITDA are statistically significant, whereas the second approach finds that 3 other parameters are statistically significant. I think that one approach is better than the other. However, in this case I am not going to discuss with my professor ... Can you explain why the two approaches yield so different results?